# Extracting specific string from combobox select

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a combobox for an item list that I populate using the following code:

```
List<string> comboboxItems = new List<string>();

foreach (var p in products)
{
   var x = p.Product;

   foreach (var pn in x)
   {
      comboboxItems.Add(pn.name + " :Qty " + pn.quantity_available
                         + " :Tax " + pn.default_tax_tier);                       
   }
}

cmbItems.DataSource = comboboxItems;
```

What should I do in order to get the value, pn.name only when the combobox item is selected?

Using WinForms.

Comment: is it WPF or Winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the event `DataGridView.EditingControlShowing` event, in there you can access the actual combobox and register the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler like this:

```
//EditingControlShowing event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
                                   DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e){
   if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == cmbItems){
     var combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
     combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= cmbItems_SelectedIndexChanged;
     combo.SelectedIndexChanged += cmbItems_SelectedIndexChanged;
   }   
}
private void cmbItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   var combo = sender as ComboBox;
   //Note that SelectedItem may be null
   var s = Convert.ToString(combo.SelectedItem);
   int i = s.IndexOf(" :Qty");
   var selectedName = i == -1 ? "" : s.Substring(0,i+1).TrimEnd();
   //other code ...
}
```

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau see the updated code right in the second method `cmbItems_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: This is just what I needed. Just added .Trim() to the end of your last statement and works perfectly. +1

Comment: @EmmadKareem it's from your tag **`datagridcomboboxcolumn`**, so I guessed your `cmbItems` is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, not a `ComboBox`, however if it's just a combobox, the code is much simpler to attach the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

Comment: Yes, cmbItems is a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0):

you should create an item such as

```
public class CboItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

then you can create easily using something like

```
CboItem item = new CboItem();
item.Text = "My Item";
item.Value = "Anything";
```

in the Value you can store your `var pn` whatever it is.
then you can retrieve like so :

```
((CboItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value;
```

You will need to cast the result above to the proper type you stored inside as the `Value` is of type object.

Answer (score 0):

We can also regular expressions to extract data from string.

Create string variable in the below format

```
string inputPattern = "{0} :Qty {1} :Tax {2}";
```

While inserting the data into combo box,

```
 comboboxItems.Add(string.Format(inputPattern, p.Name, p.Quantity_Available, p.Tax));
```

After you added it, to extract the strings we can use Regex, code snippet below.

```
string extractPattern = "(?<Name>.*) :Qty (?<Qty>.*) :Tax (?<Tax>.*)";
        foreach (var item in (comboBox1.DataSource as List<string>))
        {
            var matches = Regex.Match(item, extractPattern);
            if (matches.Groups["Name"].Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(matches.Groups["Name"].Value);
            }
            if (matches.Groups["Qty"].Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(matches.Groups["Qty"].Value);
            }
            if (matches.Groups["Tax"].Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(matches.Groups["Tax"].Value);
            }
        }
```